# Is a map between Riemannian manifolds with bounded derivative Lipschitz?

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, lipschitz-functions

Let $X,Y$ be Riemannian manifolds. Let $f:X \to Y$ be an everywhere differentiable map, such that the operator norm $\|df_p\|_{op}$ is globally bounded (from above) by $L$.

Is it true that $f$ is Lipchitz? (what about $L$-Lipschitzity?)

I am interested in the general question in the case of *low regularity*, i.e I do not assume $f$ is $C^1$ (then it's [quite easy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450725/lipschitz-maps-between-riemannian-manifolds)). In particular this means that for a smooth path $\alpha:I \to X$, we do not know a-priori that $f\circ \alpha$ is Lipschitz, so we cannot necessarily write its length as the integral of its speed.

Note that in the case where $X,Y$ are Euclidean spaces, the answer is positive and is known as the "mean value inequality". However, the standard proof does not seem to pass over to the general case.

**Updated "conjecture":**

I guess $f$ does have to be Lipschitz, and even $L$-Lipschitz.

First, since locally the Riemannian metric is "close" to Euclidean metric, I guess one could claim local-Lipschitzity certainly holds (admittedly, some details are probably required to justify this rigorously).

Then, for any smooth path $\alpha$ in $X$, $f \circ \alpha$ will also be locally-Lipchitz and (compactness?) even Lipchitz. So we can express its length as the integral of its speed, so $f$ will be $L$-Lipschitz by the usual argument.

Comment: I don't see how, even in the Euclidean case, you are concluding that $f$ is Lipschitz. It works on sets of bounded diameter, but then the Lipschitz constant tends toward $\infty$ as the diameter gets large. I would expect that your result is true if $X$ is compact, and that the Lipschitz constant depends on the diameter of $X$.

Comment: But yes, if you can do it locally then a partition of unity argument together with the Lebesgue number lemma will give you a global result.

Comment: @treble Yes, you are probably right. I was implicitly thinking on convex domains. Since Riemannian manifolds are length spaces this should pose no problem in the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed true. Proving that $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz is a local problem. Consider a path $p: [a,b]\to X$ satisfying $|p'(t)|=1$ and the composition $q=f\circ p$.

Set $y_0:= q(a)$ and consider also the distance function $d_{y_0}: Y\to {\mathbb R}$, given by $d(y_0, y)$. Since the problem is local, it suffices to consider the case when the image of $q$ is contained in a convex neighborhood $U$ of $y_0$; in this neighborhood the distance function $d_{y_0}$ is differentiable away from $y_0$; it is also 1-Lipschitz (by the triangle inequality). Hence, the norm of its gradient is $\le 1$ in $U$ (away from $y_0$ of course).

Now, consider the composition $h(t):= d_{y_0}\circ q(t)$. This function is differentiable on the interval $(a,b)$ and continuous on $[a,b]$; it also satisfies $|h'(t)|\le L$ on $(a,b)$ (the Chain rule). Hence, by the Mean Value Theorem, 
$$
d(q(a), q(b))= h(b)\le L|b-a|. 
$$
It follows that the map $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz.

Comment: Thanks! Two points: (1) Do you know a good reference on the differentiability of the distance function $d_p$? (I have searched quite hard, and found several things, but no that proof $d_p$ is differentiable at the points $q$ where there is a unique minimizing geodesic from $p$ to $q$. It is easy to see that if $d_p$ is differentiable at $q$, then there is at most one minimizing geodesic connecting them but the other direction seems less trivial for me). (2) I am still wondering if the way I suggested (in the question) works,

Comment: namely it is supposed to be easy  to show $f$ is Lipschitz locally (since everything is "close" to be Euclidean) and hence we can use the expression for the length as an integral, from where $L$-Lipschitzity follows immediately. (I somehow feel this is more elementary since we do not need to use any known facts about differentiability of $d_p$).

Comment: Why is the problem local? The points are are trying to compare $f$ at could be far apart, no?

Comment: @0celo7 think about the effect of f on the length of a curve connecting your points.